# VBA: How to remove the "Disabled" attribute from an HTML element

Tags: javascript, excel, html, vba

Working on a project with VBA that fills in a web form. I've got an Input element (an 'Add' button) selected with disabled attribute in it.

```
<input id="ClickMe" value="Add" name="BigButton" class="submit-this" disabled="">
```

Normally disabled is cleared when the user fills in the form; however since I'm interacting with the objects directly, I'm not triggering that action.
My understanding is that the only way I can 'click' this button is if I remove the disabled attribute itself (IE, Disabled="False" would not work.)

Additionally, I'm doing this through Excel 2010 on a 64-bit system. Which, I've read doesn't allow me to insert Javascript code as a workaround (ScriptControl library only supported on Excel 2010 32-bit).

How do I remove an attribute from an HTML element using VBA? 
Alternatively- is there a way to still use Javascript in excel 2010?

Comment: In javascript you could also use [*removeAttribute*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) or `element.disabled = false` (capitalisation matters). Dunno about VBA, it's a horrid language.

Comment: Is there an URL you can share for this?